# Facebook individual notification "mark as read" button is gone

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

Facebook used to have a "mark as read" button that would appear while hovering the mouse over an unread notification. Now, instead of that, I see an ellipsis with options to "Hide this notification" or "Turn off notifications about this post".

There is just the "mark all as read" link at the top.

Is there a way to mark a single notification as read?

Note that I am using the website in Chrome, not the mobile app.

Comment: Can you try this with some other browser as well? Facebook keep changing and testing new things, but I am not sure about this update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Mark As Read" option is still there; it's just hard to see.  Below the ellipsis is a single dot -- if you hover over this dot, "Mark As Read" will appear. Clicking on the dot will mark the notification as read. (Clicking on it again will mark it as unread.)

It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: I know that I didn't have it there yesterday. Facebook must have fixed it.

Comment: I will mark this as accepted, I guess. It must have been a temporary bug.